# Probing energy level repulsion from Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chaos-theory

If I have a quantum system with energy levels that exhibit random matrix statistics (so basically level repulsion).
I would like to study the thermodynamics of such systems, maybe see a macroscopic effect due to level repulsion, how should proceed?

I have the density-density correlator (that highlight the energy level repulsion at microscopic level), from which I can deduce the product of two partition functions that does not factorize due to interaction. And then in terms of thermodynamics variable I have something like:

$E_1 + E_2 $+ correction

$S_1 +S_2 +$ correction

But there is no clear meaning of each correction. Is there another way to understand the thermodynamics of such a system? My question is general, it could be applied to any quantum chaotic system, for example.